# Does Battlefield 4 allow cross platform multiplayer?

Tags: battlefield-4

I want to buy Battlefield 4 for PS3, and my brother has it for PS4. Can we play together even though we are on different generations?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot play together, it seems that the PS3 and the PS4 multiplayers use different versions of the Playstation Network due to architecture differences.

[Source](http://news.cnet.com/8301-33620_3-57612468-278/for-battlefield-4-players-a-move-to-xbox-one-ps4-means-leaving-friends-behind/)

Answer (score 1):

No.  [Battlefield 4 does not support cross-platform multiplayer](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/BF4-Cross-Platform-multiplayer/td-p/1780015).  Basically, there are two different versions of Microsoft Live and PSN [running right now](http://www.extremetech.com/gaming/171116-battlefield-4-transfers-are-one-way-one-time-only-and-theres-no-cross-generation-play).  Also, if you upgrade from PS3 to PS4, it's [only one way and requires you to lose the PS3 version](http://www.psu.com/forums/showthread.php/320592-Beware!-Upgrade-BF4-from-PS3-to-PS4-unlocks-ect?p=6246924).